# expansion of Bessel function $J_1$

Tags: calculus, power-series, special-functions, taylor-expansion

this is a general question.  Is there a general way to expand the Bessel Function $J_1(z)$ when $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and when z is large?  Or in other words, what is the asymptotic expansion of $J_1(z)$? I think it is sufficient to just use
$$
J_1(z)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} e^{-i(z-\pi/4)},\quad 0<\arg z<\pi.
$$
Is this correct? The general power series expansion is given by
$$
J_1(z)=\frac{z}{2}\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!\Gamma(k+2)} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k}.
$$
For $z\to 0$, it is sufficient to keep the lower order terms, thus we can write something like
$$
J_1(z)\approx \frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^3}{16}.
$$

Thanks, see here for more details of what I just wrote: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: Well done!  It seems that you've answered your own question.  What is left?  The only thing to add is the expansion for $-\pi<\arg z<0$.

Comment: Ok just wanted to clarify, thanks. Is there a trivial way to take the Real part of $J_1(z)$ using the series expansion?  It seems to get a bit nasty because of the $1/\sqrt z$ factor..Thanks Dr.MV

Comment: You just need to be careful about which branch you're on.  You gave the result for $0<\arg z<\pi$.  So, $z=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$ on that branch and you should have it.  $z^{1/2}=|z|^{1/2}e^{i\arg(z)/2}$ with $0<\frac12 \arg z<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: makes sense.  Thanks a lot Dr.MV!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.